# Installing UDFs in Netezza (Aginity)

Tags: sql, group-concat, netezza, udf

I'm trying to use the GROUP_CONCAT() UDF in a Netezza query but I have no idea how to install the function into my database! I've downloaded the c++ code and there's an installer in the folder but I don't know how to run that!

I've been googling it for about a day now with no luck. I'm using a Windows computer and am running Netezza through Aginity.

Would anyone be able to help me out?

Thanks in advance,
Conor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UDFs are installed through a command line interface on the Netezza host, and not through SQL.  You will need to sftp the source code to the host, connect with an SSH tool (e.g. putty or the Aginity SSH client under Tools->SSH Terminal), and run the install script from there.  Your database login will not work for logging into the host.  You may have to work with your administrator to get access.

Here is an exmaple of innstalling the c++ version of GROUP_CONCAT into a database called TESTDB.

```
[nz@netezza group_concat]$ ls -1
GroupConcat.cpp
GroupConcatSep.cpp
install
[nz@netezza group_concat]$ ./install testdb
CREATE AGGREGATE
Created uda
Done
CREATE AGGREGATE
Created uda
Done
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll get onto the admin now to get it setup!! :)